# Why is length different when returning from a function

Tags: shell-script

Do you know why the following gives different length of array, even returning it as `"${distro[@]}"`?

one.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./two.sh
    
hello(){
  arr=$(get_array)
  echo "Length arr:" "${#arr[@]}" # array is not preserved and returns 1, but why?
  show_length # returns length as correct 3
}

"$@"
```

two.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

get_array(){
  distro=("redhat linux" "debian linux" "gentoo linux")
  echo "${distro[@]}"
}

show_length(){
  distro=("redhat linux" "debian linux" "gentoo linux")
  echo "Length distro:  ${#distro[@]}"
}
```

Why:

```
sh ./one.sh hello
Length arr: 1
Length distro:  3
```

Comment: start by creating an example in one file. That way you will show your brain that it has nothing to do with multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return an array from a function with `echo "${distro[@]}"`. All it does, is print to the function's stdout, and that's only a stream of bytes, with no structure, it can't keep distinct array elements separate.

What actually happens there, is that `"${distro[@]}"` expands to multiple distinct arguments, that all get passed to `echo`, and then `echo` prints them joined with spaces. In effect, it turns your three-element array (`redhat linux`, `debian linux`, `gentoo linux`) into the single string
`redhat linux debian linux gentoo linux`.

Correspondingly, `arr=$(get_array)` is also a scalar assignment, it reads that the stdout of `get_array` as one string, and assigns it to `arr`. (`arr=( $(get_array) )` would include an array assignment, and it'd subject the command substitution to word-splitting and globbing, producing with the default settings the *six-element* array (`redhat`, `linux`, `debian`, `linux`, `gentoo`, `linux`) from that output. )

---

The workarounds for this would be e.g. printing the array elements with e.g. a newline as the delimiter, and reading that into an array at the other end, using something smarter than plain word splitting; or passing a *name* of an array to the inner function and having it store the data there.

With `readarray` (from Bash 4.0), printing the values one per line

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    local arr=("foo bar" "doo")
    printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
}
readarray -t arr2 < <(foo)
printf "read %d elements: " "${#arr2[@]}"
printf "<%s> " "${arr2[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

Though if the array is empty, `printf` still prints one newline, and the result at the other end will be a one-element array.

Or, we could use a NUL byte as the separator (from Bash 4.4), allowing passing arbitrary array elements, and fix the empty array issue too:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    local arr=("foo bar" $'new\nline')
    if (( ${#arr[@]} )); then
        printf "%s\0" "${arr[@]}"
    fi
}
readarray -t -d '' arr2 < <(foo)
# use declare -p for unambiguous shell-quoted output
declare -p arr2
```

Or with namerefs by passing the variable name:

```
#!/bin/bash
bar() {
    local arr=("foo bar" "doo")
    declare -n _name="$1"
    _name=("${arr[@]}")
}
bar arr2
printf "got %d elements: " "${#arr2[@]}"
printf "<%s> " "${arr2[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

Comment: Using `readarray -td ''` (and `printf '%s\0'`)  in `bash` 4.4+ would allow passing arbitrary element values.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` prints one empty record if the array is empty. Defining functions like `println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }` or `print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }` helps.